# Php Facebook api request for birthday

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk

I've got a website that uses register/login with facebook account. It's working fine, but i would like to also retrieve the user birthday.

All the requests that i make to graph the birthday does not come. If i only request birthday, it only comes with id.

I'm testing with my own account... and i've got the permissions for birthday set to public, and in the dev apps, the App permissions, are set to: user_about_me, user_birthday.

But i still cannot request birthday. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Permissions you set in the app dashboard are for automatic login for users coming to the app through the app center only (as the description there already says …) – whenever you are handling login yourself, you have to use the `scope` parameter to request permissions …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the permissions in your login code. Just like this-

[if using Javascript SDK]

```
FB.login(function(response) {

}, {scope: 'user_about_me,user_birthday'});
```

Comment: Im not using javascript sdk, but PHP sdk... but the response still correct, thanks +1